# Point appears in wrong place, seems like wrong SpatialReference

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm using the code below to render a point on the map but the point is in the wrong place. The coordinate system is `28992` which is a local system for the Netherlands.

Instead of the point being rendered in the Netherlands, it's rendered off the coast of Africa (near, but not on, (0,0) lat/lng). <s>I suspect that maybe the web mercator system `102100` is applied instead of the `28992`.</s> I have a new theory: in the definition of `28992` there is: `"Central_Meridian": 5.38763888888889, "Latitude_Of_Origin": 52.15616055555555`, it's like this is 0,0 instead. So the point renders with the wrong offset.

I'm fairly new to using ESRI/arcGIS so maybe I made a very basic mistake.

```
var map;
map = new Map(container_div_id, {
    basemap: "topo",
    locale: "nl",
    center: [5.523682, 52.150892],  // center of NL
    zoom: 1
});
map.on("load", function (event) {
    var point, graphic, markerSymbol;
    markerSymbol = new PictureMarkerSymbol({ ... });
    point = new esri.geometry.Point(140255.23099999875, 398772.03599999845,
        new esri.SpatialReference(28992));
    graphic = new esri.Graphic(point, markerSymbol);
    map.graphics.add(graphic);
});
```

Rendering points in other systems (ie. `102100` WGS84-projection and `4326` WGS84-geographic) works just fine.

References:

- [List of projections](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/pcs.html)
- [esri.geometry.Point](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/point-amd.html) API

---

<s>Edit: using jbchurchill's suggestion:</s>

```
map.on("load", internal_utils.try_catch(function (event) {
    map.spatialReference = new esri.SpatialReference(28992);
    ..
    point = new esri.geometry.Point(140255.23099999875, 398772.03599999845, new esri.SpatialReference(28992));
    ..
}));
```

This has the same result.

Comment: These coordinates 140255.23099999875, 398772.03599999845 don't look like the ones you are using for your map.

Comment: @jbchurchill the center coordinate is in WGS84, just basic lat,lng. `140255.23099999875, 398772.03599999845` is most certainly an RD coordinate (`28992`). I think I'm allowed to use different coordinate systems interchangably (in fact, in the full code I am).

Comment: Instead of specifying 28992, you could try setting it to map.spatialReference. That works for my maps. My answer was off base (I forgot how that spatialReference object works) so I deleted it.

Comment: @jbchurchill see updated code above, did I change it correctly? The way I changed it now doesn't work (same result).

Comment: What I'm saying is to replace new esri.SpatialReference(28992)); with map.SpatialReference;

Comment: Ok, that doesn't work either (point does not render). `map.SpatialReference` is `{ latestWkid: 3857, wkid: 102100 }`

Comment: Your map center is WGS 84, where your other coordinates are Amersfoort.  You need to pick one or the other.

Comment: @MaryBeth how do I 'pick one'? If I do `center: new esri.geometry.Point(140255.23099999875, 398772.03599999845, new esri.SpatialReference(28992)),` I end up somewhere off the coast of England, and the Point I render is still in Africa.

Comment: Easiest way would likely be to convert (140255.23099999875, 398772.03599999845) to WGS84.  You can also change the map center to a coordinate within the Amersfoort system, but would need to define the  map projection earlier in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ArcGIS API for JavaScript includes code under the hood which can convert lat/long coordinates to web mercator in applications that utilize that spatial reference *automagically*, but this is not true for conceivable projection under the sun.

because of this, its not sufficient for you to just appropriately define a custom projection for your point and get it to draw in an application that uses a web mercator basemap.  you'd have to use a [GeometryService](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/geometryservice-amd.html) (which fires off a web request) or some other mechanism to ensure that the coordinates are reprojected appropriately **before** they are added to the map.

more info can be found in a blog i wrote [here](https://geonet.esri.com/groups/geodev/blog/2014/11/03/use-proj4js-alongside-the-arcgis-api-for-javascript-to-reproject-coordinates-on-the-fly).

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to check if the map supports a `SpatialReference`?

Comment: you can certainly interrogate the 'spatialReference' of your own map via its corresponding property https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#spatialreference

Answer (score 1):

The coordinates you're using for centering the map are WGS1984. 
If you use RD-coordinates (The Dutch Amersfoort-system) it will center correctly.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. How should I change the code? How do I use an RD-coordinate for the center? How does that affect the coordinates of the point?

Comment: Like jbchurchill said: You are using coordinates with different projections in one web application. By default WGS1984 is used. Try to convert the coordinates to this projection and check if the results satify you.

Comment: that's the point of course, I don't want to convert them. Why would there be a projection parameter if I can't use a different projection? I can use WGS84 projection and geographic interchangably just fine (ofcourse after changing the coordinate numbers), and I have a feature layer defined in RD and that renders fine.

Comment: @jbchurchill I don't understand your suggestion. Can you show in code when you mean?

Comment: You can only use one projection at the time. So you need to choose.

Comment: @Stefan then how come I can use `102100` and `4326` in the same map? Is that the same projection? And how come I can use a featureset defined in `28992`? Is there an automatisch translation somewhere?